# Getting total number of comments of post in mysql using count() always returns 1 even if no comment is present for particular post

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

I have two tables in my database

1.Stories (id,title,content)

2.Comments (id,story_id,comment) here `story_id` is forigen key refers `id` in `stories` table.

In order to get the comments of a particular post i am using this query

```
SELECT stories.*,COUNT(stories.id) as totalcomment
FROM stories LEFT JOIN comments ON stories.id=comments.story_id  GROUP BY stories.id
```

Problem is i will get `totalcomment` value is 1  even if no comments for a particular post it should be 0 ,but i will get `count(storie.id)` result as 1

Comment: you need to count `Comments.story_id` and also group by `Comments.story_id`

Comment: Thakns dude its worked:) ,please put it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to count `Comments.story_id` and also group by `Comments.story_id`.

You have more than one comments for each stories, so your result goes always 1 when you group by that `stories.id`, you need to count the `Comments.story_id` so that for each stories it counts all the comments at once and also make a group by of it.

**SQL**

```
SELECT stories.*,COUNT(Comments.story_id) as totalcomment
FROM stories LEFT JOIN comments ON stories.id=comments.story_id  GROUP BY stories.id, Comments.story_id
```

Comment: I have one doubt,why did i need two  grpup by clause

Comment: group by may be effected on it cause you have multiple rows of `story_id`, so after group by of it, this is collapse to one and count works perfectly.